# How to allow additional 3rd party React modules to be installed after compilation of a static web server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, material-ui, node-modules

Struggling with collision of technical terms (most especially the term "plugin" which has about seven different meanings within the react development stack).

Short question:

Is there a way to pre-compile static webpack modules that can be installed separately from a main static react web application, while still sharing modules contained in the main web application? (The question as best I can formulate it using my relatively naïve react developer skills). I'd like the ability to plug in web user interface components supplied by 3rd party developers after the fact. i.e. installable runtime React UI components, not requiring react compilation at install time.

Details:

I have a static React web app that allows remote control of audio plugins (specifically LV2 audio plugins). It's a single-page static react app (that communicates via we sockets with the running application), hosted by a static C++ web server. Realtime and IOT agility requirements make a python hosted dynamic web server an runtime compilation an unattractive prospect (https://github.com/rerdavies/pipedal)

What I want to do is allow extension of the web UI using separate bundles provided by 3rd-party LV2 plugins. The ideal solution would be to allow static webpack bundles pre-compiled by the lv2 plaigns and placed in /usr/lib/lv2/<pluginname.lvw>/resource directories to be consumed by the web app at runtime. I'm using a custom C++ web server, so redirecting URLs into the /usr/lib/lv2/xx/resource directories is straightforward.

The main app would be distributed one apt package. Lv2 plugins would be compiled (potentially by 3rd party developers) against an "sdk package" provided by the main app build, after the main app was built, and then distributed in separate packages. Ideally, I'd like to pre-compile the ui code for the plugins to static webpack modules before their installers are built.

I more-or-less understand how I would do this if I were using raw CLI tools and configuration files (tsc, webpack, babel). But I can't help thinking I would be reinventing a wheel. (And I do have concerns that I'm going to incur serious version-dependency problems).

I would like to code-share the base modules (react, @mui controls, and a limited set of app-supplied components and interfaces).

I see the path through the various tools to make this happen, using my own custom build script, I think. I can get the typescript compiler to do code-splitting; I can probably figure out how to get the babel transpiler to do the right thing. And I think I understand how to write webpack configuration files that will process do sharing of modules from the main app. And a likely path to build and distribute an npm package to do the setup and build of LV2 plugin projects. And how to write supporting CMake build rules for building and installing such packages. &c. But I'm concerned that I'm going to go down a large rabbit hole trying to reinvent something that surely must exist already. And I can imagine seven thousand ways for this to go horribly wrong. :-P

So far, I have implemented the TypeScript compiler portion of the build procedure. And writing various bits to dynamicall intercept and service resource requests in the web server is trivial. But it has become painfully obvious that I also need to do babel and webpack build steps as well.

I haven't yet looked at the react-scripts package contents to see if I can steal code to build what I want there. Perhaps that's a viable path.

Is there a way to do this with off-the-shelf npm packages and off-the-shelf npm build procedures? I can find all kinds of bits to get me part way; but the integration of all the bits is rather daunting. Should I just do the deed, and start writing my own custom build scripts to make this happen?

Comment: I'm assuming that I will have to implement some kind of "manifest" functionality, that will be updated at load time, and a registration procedure on client-side. (I'm already walking the configuration files of installed plugins at load time). I do, in fact, have the ability to inject non-static (uncompiled) content or dynamically generated json into the client.